# Condensing similar rows occuring in groups and keeping order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an sql table containing the gps coordinates of a device, updated every *n* minutes (the device is installed in a vehicle).  given the nature of GPS, lots of the entries are very similar, but entirely different as far as the server is concerned.  I can approximately match things (within ~3.6' or maybe 36') easy enough with `CAST(lat as decimal(7,4))`

I'd like to be able to take a result set and condense the approximate duplicate entries, but still maintain the time-based order.  here's an example:

```
Row    Lat         Lng        vel Hdg Time
01    31.12345    -88.12345   00  00  12-4-21 01:45:00
02    31.12346    -88.12345   00  00  12-4-21 01:46:00
03    31.12455    -88.12410   10  01  12-4-21 01:47:00
04    31.12495    -88.12480   17  01  12-4-21 01:48:00
05    31.12532    -88.12560   22  01  12-4-21 01:49:00
06    31.12567    -88.12608   25  02  12-4-21 01:50:00
07    31.12638    -88.12672   24  02  12-4-21 01:51:00
08    31.12689    -88.12722   19  02  12-4-21 01:52:00
09    31.12345    -88.12345   00  00  12-4-21 01:53:00
10    31.12346    -88.12346   00  00  12-4-21 01:54:00
11    31.12347    -88.12345   00  00  12-4-21 01:55:00
12    31.12346    -88.12346   00  00  12-4-21 01:56:00
13    31.12689    -88.12788   10  40  12-4-21 01:57:00
14    31.12604    -88.12691   13  39  12-4-21 01:58:00
15    31.12572    -88.12603   15  39  12-4-21 01:59:00
```

my desired end result would be rows 1 and 2 to be condensed to a single row, and rows 9 through 12 be condensed to a single row, containing `AVG(Lat)`, `AVG(Lng)`, and `MIN(Time)`.

This is the result set i would like to receive, given the above data:

```
Row    Lat         Lng        vel Hdg Time
01    31.123455   -88.12345   00  00  12-4-21 01:45:00
02    31.12455    -88.12410   10  01  12-4-21 01:47:00
03    31.12495    -88.12480   17  01  12-4-21 01:48:00
04    31.12532    -88.12560   22  01  12-4-21 01:49:00
05    31.12567    -88.12608   25  02  12-4-21 01:50:00
06    31.12638    -88.12672   24  02  12-4-21 01:51:00
07    31.12689    -88.12722   19  02  12-4-21 01:52:00
08    31.12346    -88.123455  00  00  12-4-21 01:53:00
09    31.12689    -88.12788   10  40  12-4-21 01:57:00
10    31.12604    -88.12691   13  39  12-4-21 01:58:00
11    31.12572    -88.12603   15  39  12-4-21 01:59:00
```

the boundaries between groupings would be movement.  velocity being > 0, or gps coordinate changing more than *x* amount.  in this case, *x* is .0001.  **the problem**, as described below, is that multiple stops (AT DIFFERENT TIMES) at a given coordinate are lumped into a single stop.  if i visit *coordinate x* today at 4 pm, and tomorrow at 8 am, and then again at 6 pm, the only one i see is the tomorrow @ 6 pm (in the case of `MAX(Time)`) or the today @ 4 pm (in the case of `MIN(Time)`).

It's a given that if velocity is 0, heading is also 0.  It is, however, important that rows 1 and 2, and 9 through 12 not be grouped TOGETHER if their coordinates are similar enough to be the same (i.e. when rounded to 4 decimal places).

i have a query that does just that:

```
SELECT Geography::Point(AVG(dbo.GPSEntries.Latitude), 
                        AVG(dbo.GPSEntries.Longitude),
                        4326 ) as Location,
       dbo.GPSEntries.Velocity,
       dbo.GPSEntries.Heading,
       MAX(dbo.GPSEntries.Time) as maxTime,
       MIN(dbo.GPSEntries.Time) as minTime,
       AVG(dbo.RFDatas.RSSI) as avgRSSI,
       COUNT(1) as samples

FROM dbo.GPSEntries
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.Reports ON
             dbo.GPSEntries.Report_Id = dbo.Reports.Id 
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.RFDatas ON
             dbo.GPSEntries.Report_Id = dbo.RFDatas.Report_Id

GROUP BY CAST(Latitude as Decimal(7,4)),
         CAST(Longitude as Decimal(7,4)),
         Velocity,
         Heading

ORDER BY MAX(Time)
```

in other words, if i travel from point A to point B, stay for 30 minutes (and 30 reports at 1 per minute), then travel to point C, stay for 20 minutes, then travel back to point B and stay for 20 more minutes before heading to point D, i would like to be able to see both separate stops at point B.

Here's some actual data from my db, sanitized to protect the innocent, or to blame someone in north east alabama.

```
Latitude    Longitude   Spd Vel MAX(Time)               MIN(Time)                sig RowCount    
34.747420   -86.302580  68  157 2012-06-13 01:31:37.000 2012-06-13 01:31:37.000  -91   1
34.759140   -86.307620  61  134 2012-06-13 01:33:06.000 2012-06-13 01:33:06.000  -91   2
34.763237   -86.307264  0   0   2012-06-13 01:34:36.000 2012-06-12 01:27:21.000  -97   7
34.763288   -86.307280  0   0   2012-06-13 14:30:44.000 2012-06-12 01:30:21.000  -98 527
34.760220   -86.308200  38  110 2012-06-13 14:33:44.000 2012-06-13 14:33:44.000  -98   1
34.750350   -86.305750  5   90  2012-06-13 14:35:13.000 2012-06-13 14:35:13.000  -83   2
34.737160   -86.298040  70  88  2012-06-13 14:36:43.000 2012-06-13 14:36:43.000  -80   1
34.736420   -86.277270  120 33  2012-06-13 14:38:13.000 2012-06-13 14:38:13.000  -87   2
34.747090   -86.248370  120 37  2012-06-13 14:39:43.000 2012-06-13 14:39:43.000  -93   2
34.755620   -86.240640  70  179 2012-06-13 14:41:13.000 2012-06-13 14:41:13.000  -81   1
34.771240   -86.242760  70  0   2012-06-13 14:42:42.000 2012-06-13 14:42:42.000  -88   2
34.785510   -86.245710  70  6   2012-06-13 14:44:12.000 2012-06-13 14:44:12.000  -99   2
34.800220   -86.239400  70  1   2012-06-13 14:45:42.000 2012-06-13 14:45:42.000  -86   1
34.815070   -86.232180  70  16  2012-06-13 14:47:12.000 2012-06-13 14:47:12.000  -98   2
34.824540   -86.226198  0   0   2012-06-13 14:51:41.000 2012-06-13 00:13:48.000 -101   9
34.824579   -86.226171  0   0   2012-06-14 00:26:19.000 2012-06-12 00:46:57.000  -99 168
```

You'll note the 4th and last row have 527 and 168 entries, respectively, and they span 2 days.  those entries are from 1 device only, and are from where the device was stopped for several hours in the same place *on multiple occasions*.

Here's some zipped csv data: [sample](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1325695/gpsData.zip)

### What I Finally Done Did

Some minor modifications to Aaron Bertrand's supplied query shown below:

```
WITH d AS
(
  SELECT Time
        ,Latitude
        ,Longitude
        ,Velocity
        ,Heading
        ,TimeRN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Time])
  FROM dbo.GPSEntries
  GROUP BY Time, Latitude, Longitude, Velocity, Heading
),
y AS (
  SELECT BeginTime  = MIN(Time)
        ,EndTime    = MAX(Time)
        ,Latitude   = AVG(Latitude)
        ,Longitude  = AVG(Longitude)
--      ,[RowCount] = COUNT(*)
        ,GroupNumber
  FROM ( 
    SELECT  Time
           ,Latitude
           ,Longitude
           ,GroupNumber = ( 
              SELECT MIN(d2.TimeRN)
              FROM d AS d2
              WHERE d2.TimeRN >= d.TimeRN AND
              NOT EXISTS ( 
                SELECT 1
                FROM d AS d3    -- Between 250 and 337 feet
                WHERE ABS(d2.Latitude - d.Latitude) <= .0007 AND   
                      ABS(d2.Longitude - d.Longitude) <= .0007 AND
                      d2.Velocity = d.Velocity ) )
    FROM d ) AS x
  GROUP BY GroupNumber
)
SELECT y.Latitude
      ,y.Longitude
      ,d.Velocity
      ,d.Heading
      ,y.BeginTime
--    ,y.EndTime
--    ,y.[RowCount]
--    ,Duration = CONVERT(time(0),DATEADD(SS,DATEDIFF(SS,y.BeginTime, y.EndTime), '0:00:00'), 108)
FROM y INNER JOIN d ON y.BeginTime = d.[Time]
-- FOR STOPS (5 minute):
-- WHERE DATEDIFF(MI, Y.BeginTime, y.EndTime) + 1 > 5
ORDER BY y.BeginTime;
```

Comment: You seem to have some conflicting requirements, at least in the way I interpreted the question. Thank you for sample data and the query you tried, but can you also post the actual results you expect?

Comment: Is the only difference between the results you want and the results you're getting the fact that the lat/long are not averaged between "grouped" rows? The query you have already seems to generate the same number of rows, with almost the same data (you just need to add the Lat/Long columns to the SELECT list), with the right rows seemingly grouped. Can you show a case where the query groups rows together that it shouldn't have?

Comment: No, the difference is that ALL of the similar lat/longs are grouped into ONE group, while i'm looking to get a Time-Linear(??) set, where some _point x_ will show up several times SEQUENTIALLY, then several more times SEQUENTIALLY _LATER_.  i want that to be 2 "groupings," or more to the point, i only want ONE row _per sequence_ back, which would be the one represented by the row containing MIN(Time).

Comment: So if a device has left a position (meaning lat/lon has changed enough to see a difference in convert(decimal(7,4))), then come back even 5 minutes later, you want that to be a new "island" so to speak? If this is the case, can you remove all of the tabular results you have now, and show a smaller set of original data that contains these islands, and the results you want from that? It's very hard to jump between the data you show up top (with no such islands) and correlate it to the 527+ rows down below (which had islands in the source that we can't see).

Comment: perhaps this will help clear the mud a bit.  imagine the first result set posted above, with 15 rows, is a record of you getting in your car that has been parked for 2 minutes (the first 2 rows), pulling out of a parking lot, driving for 6 minutes (rows 3 through 8), and parking back in the lot, but one space over, and staying for 4 minutes (rows 9 through 12), then leaving again (rows 13+).  my above posted query will truncate the coordinates at 4 decimal places before grouping them, so rows 1 and 2, and rows 9 through 12 will appear to be "groupable", when in fact, they are 2 different trips

Comment: I get the real life analogy. I need to be able to relate that to the data, and I can't, because the sample source data doesn't show me coming back to the lot.

Comment: I've changed the sample data to reflect the question.  your assumptions are correct.  if you want a sample of my actual data, the "islands" are actually my work day and my post-work at-home time, so they're between 9 and 14 hours wide, with samples every 1.5 minutes or so.  i.e. lots of rows.  is the false data usable as is, since changing?

Comment: Did you intend for the sample csv data you posted to have duplicates (and lots of them)? Rows 1 and 3 are identical, rows 2 and 4, rows 8 and 10, etc. I had to adjust my answer to deal with those; I suspect they don't really exist in the source data, in which case you can take out the grouping I added to my initial CTE.

Comment: That isn't sample data, it's the actual data.  the identical, probably mostly twin, data is probably from the device having 2 servers to contact to report coordinates to, one for redundancy, coupled with my inability to respond with an ACK until AT&T provides me with a different APN to connect to.  Something i should correct, but i just haven't gotten around to yet.  i'm still writing the server side, too. :)

Comment: FYI by "sample data" I didn't mean "fake data" I meant the data your provided. I assume those ~450 rows don't represent *all* of your "actual data."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample data in tempdb:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.GPSEntries
( 
  Latitude DECIMAL(8,5), 
  Longitude DECIMAL(8,5), 
  Velocity TINYINT, 
  Heading TINYINT, 
  [Time] SMALLDATETIME
);

INSERT dbo.GPSEntries VALUES
 (31.12345,-88.12345,00,00,'2012-04-21 01:45:00'),
 (31.12346,-88.12345,00,00,'2012-04-21 01:46:00'),
 (31.12455,-88.12410,10,01,'2012-04-21 01:47:00'),
 (31.12495,-88.12480,17,01,'2012-04-21 01:48:00'),
 (31.12532,-88.12560,22,01,'2012-04-21 01:49:00'),
 (31.12567,-88.12608,25,02,'2012-04-21 01:50:00'),
 (31.12638,-88.12672,24,02,'2012-04-21 01:51:00'),
 (31.12689,-88.12722,19,02,'2012-04-21 01:52:00'),
 (31.12345,-88.12345,00,00,'2012-04-21 01:53:00'),
 (31.12346,-88.12346,00,00,'2012-04-21 01:54:00'),
 (31.12347,-88.12345,00,00,'2012-04-21 01:55:00'),
 (31.12346,-88.12346,00,00,'2012-04-21 01:56:00'),
 (31.12689,-88.12788,10,40,'2012-04-21 01:57:00'),
 (31.12604,-88.12691,13,39,'2012-04-21 01:58:00'),
 (31.12572,-88.12603,15,39,'2012-04-21 01:59:00');
```

And my attempt at satisfying the query:

```
;WITH d AS
(
    SELECT Time, Latitude, Longitude, Velocity, Heading, 
        NormLat = CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,4), Latitude), 
        NormLong = CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,4), Longitude),
        TimeRN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Time])
    FROM dbo.GPSEntries
    -- /* you probably want filters:
    -- WHERE DeviceID = @SomeDeviceID
    -- AND [Time] >= @SomeStartDate
    -- AND [Time] <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @SomeEndDate)
    -- /* also your sample CSV file had lots of duplicates, so:
    GROUP BY Time, Latitude, Longitude, Velocity, Heading
),
y AS (
  SELECT MinTime = MIN(Time), MaxTime = MAX(Time), Latitude = AVG(Latitude), 
    Longitude = AVG(Longitude), [RowCount] = COUNT(*) FROM 
    (
      SELECT Time, Latitude, Longitude, GroupNumber = 
      (
        SELECT MIN(d2.TimeRN) 
         FROM d AS d2 WHERE d2.TimeRN >= d.TimeRN 
         AND NOT EXISTS 
         (
           SELECT 1 FROM d AS d3
           WHERE d2.NormLat = d.NormLat
           AND d2.NormLong = d.NormLong
         )
       )
       FROM d
    ) AS x GROUP BY GroupNumber
)
SELECT [Row] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY y.MinTime),
  y.Latitude, y.Longitude, d.Velocity, d.Heading, 
  y.MinTime, y.MaxTime, y.[RowCount]
FROM y INNER JOIN d ON y.MinTime = d.[Time]
ORDER BY y.MinTime;
```

Results:

```
Row Latitude  Longitude  Velocity Heading MinTime          MaxTime          RowCount
---|---------|----------|--------|-------|----------------|----------------|--------
1   31.123455 -88.123450   0        0     2012-04-21 01:45 2012-04-21 01:46   2
2   31.124550 -88.124100   10       1     2012-04-21 01:47 2012-04-21 01:47   1
3   31.124950 -88.124800   17       1     2012-04-21 01:48 2012-04-21 01:48   1
4   31.125320 -88.125600   22       1     2012-04-21 01:49 2012-04-21 01:49   1
5   31.125670 -88.126080   25       2     2012-04-21 01:50 2012-04-21 01:50   1
6   31.126380 -88.126720   24       2     2012-04-21 01:51 2012-04-21 01:51   1
7   31.126890 -88.127220   19       2     2012-04-21 01:52 2012-04-21 01:52   1
8   31.123460 -88.123455   0        0     2012-04-21 01:53 2012-04-21 01:56   4
9   31.126890 -88.127880   10       40    2012-04-21 01:57 2012-04-21 01:57   1
10  31.126040 -88.126910   13       39    2012-04-21 01:58 2012-04-21 01:58   1
11  31.125720 -88.126030   15       39    2012-04-21 01:59 2012-04-21 01:59   1
```

Comment: It's not quite there.  I'm trying to work my way through it to understand what you're doing.  the nested SELECT's in `y` are still confusing me a bit.

I'm actually not sure if this is the sort of problem i should be trying to solve with sql vs doing it in c#/the application.

also, what's the first `;` for, before `WITH d`?

Comment: on further inspection, it appears that the truncation/rounding is actually causing the problem, if i truncate or round to 3 decimal places, the duplicates disappear.  So, i'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: Any statement preceding a CTE (which starts with `WITH`) must be terminated with a semi-colon. I put it at the beginning of my CTEs (since you can have as many statement terminators as you want; `SELECT 1;;;;;;;;;;;;;` is legal). This way when people copy it into their own code, they don't come back and complain (I had no idea they would paste it into a stored procedure that doesn't have statement terminators anywhere). If only [everyone started using proper statement terminators](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).